# Groovy replacing a string in JSON Block

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I have spent hours on this and getting frustrated now. I have built this string (note this string is variable but looks like below and must have the same syntax for "Id1" or "Id2" except the values can be different)

```
str1= [{"Id1": 775},{"Id2": 776}]
```

I like to replace  the entire value for myList: [{"Id": 0}], as shown below in my JSON block with that str1

```
someJson: {
    "myList": [{"Id": 0}],
}
```

SO I have

```
abc = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(someJson);
abc.myList= str1
```

My resulting output on that JSON block is this, I dont want the \  I have tried escaping but it doesnt work

```
"myList": "[{\"Id1\": 775},{\"Id2\": 776}]",
```

It looks like Groovy adds those \ right behind my "  I dont want groovy to do that. I want it to take my str1 and just replace it in mylist.  I even tried adding \ or \\ behind the " in str1  but it didnt work.

I think I have to convert str1 to a map in groovy?? so I tried

```
    abc.myList= Eval.me(str1)
```

but I am getting this error

```
Script1.groovy: 1: expecting '}', found ':' @ line 1, column 15.
   [{"Id1": 775},{"Id2": 776}]
```

Comment: You can no eval JSON as Groovy.  `{"X": 1}` is a JSON object/map - if you put that into groovy it will read the `{}` as a closure (this is basically what the error is telling you).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it ut at last

I have to create a list, then I have to iterate through the map items

```
def map = [:]
def list = []
```

iterate

```
map.clear()
map.put(Id,val);
list.add(map);
```

Comment: What iteration are you talking about? What is `Id` I assume you mean `"Id"`? You can also just use the list and map literals: `def list = [[Id: val]]`